# Dropzone.js preview dimension scale to actual image size

Tags: dropzone.js

I want to ask if there is some way to force Dropzone to use the dimension (dimension ratio) for preview, based on the uploaded image rather then specifying them in Dropzone config.

I want to display the preview of the image in the same dimensions ratio as the original, but smaller.

Thanks
Jan

Answer (score 1):

You should redefine the css styles below :

```
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-details, .dropzone-previews .dz-preview .dz-details {
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
}

.dz-details img {
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    position: relative !important;
}
```